# Excel (2010) Save and Save As operations cease working

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, save-as

Twice in the past week a colleague has encountered an issue with Excel 2010 where the application suddenly ceases to perform its Save and Save As functions on all open workbooks, with no error messages or warnings returned when pressing the associated buttons.

- The user can press 'Save' as many times as he wants, but the operation does not perform.
- When going to File > Save As, no menu appears and you land back on the Home tab.
- Our office also has an Excel add-in for 'Open Text Explorer' or 'Livelink' which is an intranet file management system, and though its Save dialogue actually allows you to navigate and give a file name, it also fails but does return an error (but we didn't log the actual message it gave).
- The only other noteworthy Excel add-in we use is 'PI Datalink' which allows us to retrieve live production figures from several company servers. This has been in-use regularly for many years, is using a recent version and has never been observed to cause any sort of application issues like this.

So whether using native Save functionality or Livelink, Excel is just plain unable to save. Save functionality is recovered once the application has been closed and re-initialised, and the documents can then be opened and saved as normal. The immediate issue can be worked around by using Send As Attachment to recover the unsaveable files before reinitialising the application.

I can't find any related threads. Has anybody encountered anything like this issue before, or have any idea on root causes?

Comment: Sounds like your add-in. Run excel in safe mode for a while and see if it happens.

Comment: PI is fairly tame but I could see the other one overwriting the the normal functionality of the save command.  Of course if there is an error in its code, you could be in limbo with default functionality broken and new functionality broken also.  Disabling the add-in will help identify the issue, but spurious problems like this are very hard to track down.  Does saving via VBA work after the button fails: `ActiveWorkbook.Save`? I don't think you can overwrite that one.  [If you want an example of repurposing a command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb462633(v=office.12).aspx).

Comment: That's a good idea - next time I'll try running a quick Save operation via VBA and see if that works, and then disable the add-ins one at a time. They're both totally normal add-ins that dozens more of us have used every day for years, so it's odd to see this behaviour just occurring for the one user. Livelink is used by still thousands more of us. If I find a resolution I'll post it here, or else I'm still open to hearing whether anybody's seen this before. Thanks @Byron